# Identify duplicates in a list of lists and sum up their last items

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists from which I would like to remove duplicates and sum up duplicates' last elements. An item is a duplicate if its first 2 elements are the same. This is better illustrated with an example:

```
input = [['a', 'b', 2], ['a', 'c', 1], ['a', 'b', 1]]

# Desired output
output = [['a', 'b', 3], ['a', 'c', 1]]
```

There are similar questions here on SO but I haven't found one which would deal with list of lists and summing up list items at the same time.

I tried several approaches but couldn't make it work:

- create a copy of input list, make a nested loop, if second duplicate is found, add its last item to original --> this got too confusing with too much nesting
- I looked into collections Counter but it doesn't seem to work with list of lists
- itertools

Could you give me any pointers on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think lists are the best data structure for it. I would use dictionaries with tuple key. I you really need list, you can create one later:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [['a', 'b', 2], ['a', 'c', 1], ['a', 'b', 1]]

result = collections.defaultdict(int) # new keys are auto-added and initialized as 0
for item in data:
    a, b, value = item
    result[(a,b)] += value
print result
# defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('a', 'b'): 3, ('a', 'c'): 1})
print dict(result)
# {('a', 'b'): 3, ('a', 'c'): 1}
print [[a, b, total] for (a, b), total in result.items()]
# [['a', 'b', 3], ['a', 'c', 1]]
```

Comment: You can make it a bit shorter: `for a, b, value in data`.

Comment: That's what my first version was, but I decided to make it more descriptive (there are also 3 lists, making it shorter could confuse someone).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Counter`; someone's already given a manual `defaultdict` solution; so here's an `itertools.groupby` one, just for variety:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> inp = [['a', 'b', 2], ['a', 'c', 1], ['a', 'b', 1]]
>>> [k[:2] + [sum(v[2] for v in g)] for k,g in groupby(sorted(inp), key=lambda x: x[:2])]
[['a', 'b', 3], ['a', 'c', 1]]
```

but I second @m.wasowski's view that a dictionary (or dict subclass like defaultdict or Counter) is probably a better data structure.

It'd also be somewhat more general to use `[:-1]` and `[-1]` instead of `[:2]` and `[2]`, but I'm too lazy to make the change. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this approach:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import repeat, chain
>>> sum((Counter({tuple(i[:-1]): i[-1]}) for i in input), Counter())
Counter({('a', 'b'): 3, ('a', 'c'): 1})
```

(Thanks to @DSM for pointing out an improvement to my original answer.)

If you want it in list form:

```
>>> [[a, b, n] for (a,b),n in _.items()]
[['a', 'b', 3], ['a', 'c', 1]]
```

Comment: Could do `sum((Counter({tuple(i[:-1]): i[-1]}) for i in inp), Counter())`, I guess.

Comment: @DSM Thanks, that's a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> t = [['a', 'b', 2], ['a', 'c', 1], ['a', 'b', 1]]
>>> sums = {}
>>> for i in t:
    sums[tuple(i[:-1])] = sums.get(tuple(i[:-1]),0) + i[-1]
>>> output = [[a,b,sums[(a,b)]] for a,b in sums]
>>> output
[['a', 'b', 3], ['a', 'c', 1]]
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about what I mean by duplicates. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
inp = [['a', 'b', 2], ['a', 'c', 1], ['a', 'b', 1], ['a', 'c', 2], ['a', 'b', 4]]

lst = []
seen = []
for i, first in enumerate(inp):
    if i in seen:
        continue
    found = False
    count = first[-1]
    for j, second in enumerate(inp[i + 1:]):
        if first[:2] == second[:2]:
            count += second[-1]
            found = True
            seen.append(i + j + 1)
    if found:
        lst.append(first[:-1] + [count])
    else:
        lst.append(first)

print(lst)
# [['a', 'b', 7], ['a', 'c', 3]]
```