# Group sum of list elements based on first and second value

Tags: python, list, sum

I have the following list:

```
mylist = [('word1', '10', 200), ('word2', '10', 450), ('word1', '136', 300), ('word2', '110', 666)]
```

I would like to know how to get the output:

```
[('10', 650), ('136',300), ('110', 666)]
```

So add positions [1] and [2] to a new list or dict. But if there is a `word1` and a `word2` with the same [1], add [1] together with the sum of both [2] to the new list or dict.

I hope I'm clear enough, otherwise ask away.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes but all failed, so im out of ideas

Comment: Please show your attempts

Comment: i tried the solution for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922086/identify-duplicates-in-a-list-of-lists-and-sum-up-their-last-items

Comment: but there [0] and [1] are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please rename your `list` list to `list_` (or something else) to not overwrite the reference to the  list built-in.

```
alrd_seen={}
for l in list_:
    alrd_seen[l[1]] = alrd_seen.get(l[1], 0) + l[2]
print list(alrd_seen.items())
```

with defaultdict;

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd
alrd_seen = dd(0)
for l in list_:
    alrd_seen[l[1]] += l[2]
print list(alrd_seen.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the variable name from `list` to something else like `lst` because that's confusing as `list` is a data type.
Try something like:

```
getfunc = lambda x, lst: sum(i[2] for i in lst if i[1] == x)
dct = { y: getfunc(y, lst) for x, y, z in lst}

print (dct)
```

gives output:

```
{'110': 666, '10': 650, '136': 300}
```

Comment: Doesn't quite give the expected output, though

Comment: how is that, whats doesn't work?

Comment: Hint: `print(dct.items())`

Comment: He said in the question right, he needs either new list or dict.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [('word1', '10', 200), ('word2', '10', 450), ('word1', '136', 300), ('word2', '110', 666)]

# Since you need to refer back to previous values while processing,
# we'll use a dictionary as intermediate storage
nl = {}
# Use unpacking to make code more readable and avoid the use of
# error-prone index-based referencing
for _, key, value in mylist:
    # Use dict.get(key, default_value_if_missing) to retrieve the
    # current value or 0 if it is a newly seen key. Add the current
    # value and store.
    nl[key] = nl.get(key, 0) + value

# dict.items() returns a "set-like" list of key-value pairs.
# Convert it to a regular list to get a list of tuples.
list(nl.items())
# [('136', 300), ('10', 650), ('110', 666)]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.